# A More Efficient Way to Query Relationships

Tags: laravel

I'm building a query on a table (product).

product has a foreign key, wrapper_id,

each wrapper, in turn, has a foreign key wrapper_classification_id.

This part of the query needs to modify the search based on an array of wrapper_classification_id's that may have been passed as input parameters.

This is what I'm doing:

```
     // $query is already being built from above this line....
     // wrapper_classification_id in input is an array

    if (Input::get('wrapper_classification_id'))
    {
        $wrappers = Wrapper::whereIn('wrapper_classification_id', Input::get('wrapper_classification_id'))->get();
        $wrapperArray = [];
        foreach($wrappers as $wrapper) {
            $wrapperArray[] = $wrapper->id;
        }
        $query->whereIn('wrapper_id', $wrapperArray );
    }
```

Is there a more efficient way of approaching this scenario where you're querying against a value in a relationship?

Thanks in advance,
Rich

Answer (score 1):

```
$query->whereIn(
    'wrapper_id', 
    DB::raw(
        Wrapper::whereIn(
            'wrapper_classification_id', 
            Input::get('wrapper_classification_id')
        )->toSql()
    )
);
```

**Or,** try joins.

```
$query->join('wrapper AS w', 'w.wrapper_classification_id', 'IN', Input::get('wrapper_classification_id'))
    ->whereIn('product.wrapper_id', 'w.id');
```

Not sure if that exact code would work though.

Answer (score 1):

Assuming the product model has a `wrapper` relationship:

```php
if (Input::has('wrapper_classification_id'))
{
    $query->whereHas('wrapper', function($q){
        $q->whereIn('wrapper_classification_id', Input::get('wrapper_classification_id'));
    });
}
```